# how to calculate outdegree of DAG which is represented using adjancency matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

i need a method to calculate outdegree of each vertex of DAG to check whether it is leaf or not.i m using java with boolean adjancency matrix representation

Comment: If you're only trying to check whether it's a leaf, you don't need to calculate the outdegree; you only need to ascertain whether the outdegree is zero.  This may turn out to be computationally simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Sum along the row.
In an adjacency matrix, there is a 1 at position (*i*, *j*) if there is an edge from vertex *i* to vertex *j*. Therefore, all the outgoing edges of vertex *i* are in row *i*. A sum of row *i* therefore gives you the outdegree of vertex *i*.

For a transposed adjacency matrix, sum along the columns.

Like David says, if you're only interested in whether the outdegree is zero or not you can save work by stopping the summation if you find a 1.